# Валидатор. Не работает @Autowired

Tags: java, spring

Создал валидатор, в котором хочу проверить существование пользователя по его ID. Задача не сложная, как раз для обучения.

Создал интерфейс

```
package com.aries.api.core.user.validate;


import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@NotNull
@Min(0)
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CheckIdValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface CheckId {
    String message() default "User not found";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

И к нему имплементацию

```
package com.aries.api.core.user.validate;

import com.aries.api.core.user.UserDao;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.aries.api.core.user.UserModel;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CheckIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CheckId, BigInteger> {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CheckId id) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(BigInteger id, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {

        System.out.println(this.userDao); // -> null

        if (id.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0) {
            UserModel user = this.userDao.get(id);

            if (user != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

В контроллере вызываю валидатор и код падает на строчке

```
System.out.println(this.userDao); // -> null
```

т.е не происходит подключение бина. Сам бин определен а applicationContext. Я его могу подключить в контроллере и получить пользователя из базы. Значит бин рабочий и все ок.

Но тогда почему он не подключается в валидаторе?

**UPDATE**

Сам валидатор вызывается так (пример нашел на просторах интернета и вставил в свой код)

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;

Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(obj);

boolean isValid = constraintViolations.isEmpty();
```

Comment: А сам валидатор определён в контексте Spring'а? Spring производит инъекции только в свои бины.

Comment: К сожалению Java учу совсем недавно. Потому я не знаю как это сделать. Можешь помочь советом, что надо сделать. Или можно линк на доку, что бы я понял направление, куда копать.

Comment: `@Autowired` не срабатывает сам по себе, ему нужно, чтобы Spring сам создавал экземпляр того класса, где нужно произвести инъекцию (на самом деле, можно извернуться, но это оотдельная тема). Простейший вариант - добавить валидатор через `@Component` в контейнер (точнее, в кандидаты при сканировании) и получать его в нужном месте через тот же `@Autowired`.

Comment: Объявите `CheckIdValidator` точно так же, как и `UserDao` в XML- или Java-конфигурации как бин Spring'а.

Comment: Это не помогло. Вызов валидатора я дополнил в основном вопросе.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. Буду переделывать логику валидирования.

Answer (score 1):

В таком случае использовать `Autowired` не получится. Spring обрабатывает только бины, созданные в его контексте. Соответственно, получать бин валидатора вам нужно не из `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator()`, а из контекста Spring'а. И создавать его там же (через XML- или Java-конфигурацию).